# How many visits to my site on digitalocean?

Tags: server, apache2

It is only html. i deployed with apache.

i do vn stat

```
caner@ubuntu:~$ vnstat
Database updated: Sun Dec 24 01:56:25 2017

   eth0 since 12/24/2017

          rx:  0 KiB      tx:  2 KiB      total:  2 KiB

   monthly
                     rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
       Dec '17         0 KiB |       2 KiB |       2 KiB |    0.00 kbit/s
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     estimated        --     |      --     |      --     |

   daily
                     rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     12/24/2017        0 KiB |       2 KiB |       2 KiB |    0.00 kbit/s
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     estimated        --     |      --     |      --     |
```

it shoews this. what does this mean, 1 click?

and why time is 24 december?i just ran this vnstat command

```
    caner@ubuntu:~$ date
Tue Dec 26 21:38:06 UTC 2017
```

i went as root

```
root@ubuntu-01:/var/log/apache2# ls
```

access.log  access.log.1  access.log.2.gz  error.log  error.log.1  error.log.2.gz  other_vhosts_access.log

other_vhosts_access.log is empty.

and access.log has newest date while access.log.1 and access.log.2gz has older date?

for exampla latest in access.log is

```
178.x2.220.63 - - [26/Dec/2017:19:59:10 +0000] "GET /audio/bryan_adamsmp3 HTTP/1.1" 206 789160 "http://xxxx.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
```

so does this mean someone visited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this can not be translated into hits directly. The data usage will vary, depending on content. Photos and videos can consume megabytes per visitor, whilst text consumes very little bandwidth.

For the number of visitors, you should look at your logfiles, typically `/var/log/apache2/access.log` - or install a tracker like [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/), which will give you improved stats.

The reason it says `eth0 since 12/24/2017` is that this is the use since that date (tracking started then probably). It seems that on the 25. and 26. there was no traffic, and thus not reported.

Furthermore, 2kiB means that you probably had zero visitors. At the most one, if it's a really simple site.

You have a service called `logrotate` that rotates logs on a daily basis. The old ones gets moved, as you see, to a new filename, and optionally compressed, being given the `.gz` suffix.

Each line in the `access.log` generally means one hit, yes.

Comment: i added question about that log. can you look. and is it possible to use with html google analytics?

Comment: Yes, GA requires only a short javascript snippet to be included in the website.

Comment: i just installed and went to website and closed. but ga showed 1 active user even i closed. https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/?authuser=0#report/content-pages/a111638696w166465653p166853036/%3F_u.dateOption%3Dlast7days/ this age shows 0 page visited.why. i put all 5 pages and to test, i visted each page

Comment: GA is not a real time tracking tool. It's closeish to realtime. Furthermore, it is mainly useful when you have more visitors, to show trends and changes... Parts of the statistics is updated daily.

Comment: can i see mobile visitors?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ubuntu. Go read the [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to track who's been accessing your website, most basically, from Apache then you should look in `/var/log/apache/access.log`. You'll see lines like "GET / HTTP/1.0 200 [PAGE]" where [PAGE] is the referrer.

Comment: i added question about that log. can you look.